# Turning QGIS Map into real time GPS for phones?

Tags: qgis, gps, real-time

I'm attempting to create a map in QGIS for use on a website that will allow users to navigate pathways in a park (i.e. choose a desired location, and be shown directions).

I'm done with the map (georeferenced, pathway/destination layers, etc.), but I'm not even quite sure that QGIS can be used for this purpose.

@BradHards- I'd like dynamic routing.

Comment: Its not really clear what you are asking for here. Perhaps you can show what you've already done, and what background and skills you have? What sort of phone environment are you targeting? Are you really trying for a phone application, or a web site? If its a web site, what sort of tools are you using? Please be much more descriptive, so we can help you. Consider taking the tour, and providing one clear, unambiguous question.

Comment: I'm trying to build a mobile GPS for people's phones so they can find their way around an amusement park.  I created a few raster layesr- I used the official park map and georeferenced it to some government ortho maps.  I don't have a preference for whether it would be an app or website, I just heard it would be easier to make a website for this purpose.  I think iPhones would be the best bet because they're more ubiquitous.  So my question is whether QGIS maps can be used for this project?

Comment: Are you trying for dynamic routing, or specific location pairs? Also, please edit the question rather than adding most of the detail in comments.